# Standar Users and wifi connection

Tags: permissions, users

I just can´t find the way to make that the system doesn´t ask for Admin pass when an standard users want to change their wifi connection.

Comment: Not a very clear question. Do you mean that every time you try accessing a different wifi connection, it asks for a password, or what? Also, what desktop environment are you using, (GNOME, Unity, KDE, etc), and what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu network-manager has two types of connections - *system connections* and *user connections*. System connections get saved in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` with mode 600 (i.e. `-rw-------`) and do require administrator privileges to create or edit.

Non-privileged users should be able to create new user-connections, however there is a wrinkle in the UI which appears to make it impossible - when the <kbd>Add</kbd> dialog is instantiated, it has the `Available to all users` checkbox pre-checked and grayed-out - this identifies the connection as a system-connection, and the non-privileged user can't save it as such - and apparently can't deselect the box to make it a (saveable) user-connection:

[image: nm-connection-editor Add]

However, once anything is typed into the SSID box (even a space) the 'Available to all users' box becomes editable:

[image: nm-connection-editor SSID]

[image: nm-connection-editor Available]

Once that box is unchecked, it should be possible for an unprivileged user to edit and save the connection properties.